# How to show/hide label depence of the position of boolean numbers "0" or "1" are. Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

if in textbox.text the value is 011, show label2 and label3 and hide label1.

If in textbox.text the value is 101 show label1, hide label2, show label3.

If in textbox.text the value is 000 hide all the labels.

If in textbox.text the value is 111 show all the labels (label1 ,label2, label3).

The same if the value in textbox.text is 00011111000001101011.

```
        //Count how digits are in textbox
       int result = textBox1.Text.Count(c => char.IsDigit(c));
       label1.Text = result.ToString();
       //find the position of '1' or '0' are
```

Comment: Put your textboxes in an array so that you can access them by numeric index. Everything else should be easy.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I think you meant put the labels in an array :-)

Comment: Can you give me an example please with 3 labels and 1 textbox?

Comment: @user10269233 Is this Windows Forms? Or something else?

Comment: Yes I need it for Windows Forms.

Comment: You should add some code otherwise nobody can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by putting your labels into an array. You could do this after the call to `InitializeComponent();`:

```cs
public class Form1
{
    private readonly List<Label> _labels;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _labels = new List<Label>() { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 };
    }
```

Then we can add a method that takes a string of 0s and 1s, loops through it, and sets the visibility of the corresponding labels in the `_labels` list:

```cs
private void SetLabelVisibility(string visString)
{
    // get the maximum number of possible labels to update
    // this is the smaller of the number of 0s and 1s in the string,
    // and the number of labels in _labels
    int maxLen = Math.Min(visString.Length, _labels.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxLen; ++i)
    {
        // check if the character is 0, 1, or other
        switch (visString[i])
        {
            case '0': // set to invisible
                _labels[i].Visible = false;
                break;
            case '1': // set to visible
                _labels[i].Visible = true;
                break;
             default: // invalid character
                 throw new ArgumentException(nameof(visString));
         }
    }
}
```

So calling `SetLabelVisibility("01101");` will leave labels 2, 3, and 5 visible, but hide labels 1 and 4.